# R Function Name - Apply Expression To List Elements Pairwise

Tags: r, function

I recall reading about a function a while ago, and I cannot seem to find it again. It starts with either a vector and an expression or an initial value, a vector, and an expression. The expression is applied to the first two elements (or initial value and first element); then the expression is applied again to the result along with the next element, and the cycle continues across the whole vector. It's not any of the apply-family functions.

```
example_function(init = 0, vec = c(1, 2, 0, 3), expr = '+')

> 1, 3, 3, 6
```

Comment: So what's your question specifically?

Comment: [`Reduce`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html)

Comment: @r2evans that is it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r2evans found the answer.
Reduce()

Specifically, it is Reduce( ... , accumulate = TRUE)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).